# Input text next to plot axes

Tags: plotting

Please see the following image showing my plot. 
[image]

I would like to indicate $\omega$ is maximized at $\bar{\omega}$. But as you can see, it is cut and does not appear correctly. Do you know how to fix this?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: In version 9.0.1.0  (Windomws 8 64bit) `Plot[{5x,10x, 20x,,x(20-x)},{x,0,20},PlotRange->{0,150},Ticks->{None,{{100,Style[Overscript["\[Omega]", _],16]}}},AxesLabel->{Style["g",16],Style["\[Omega]",16]}]`  gives the expected output -- tick label is not cut off.

Comment: @kguler, it work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot[{5 x, 10 x, 20 x, , x (20 - x)}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 150}, 
 Ticks -> {None, {{100, Style[Overscript["ω", _], 16]}}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["g", 16], Style["ω", 16]}]

Works in mathematica v10.0
I have deleted the [/Omega] and writing it back appears the Omega character.

Comment: great!, it works! I really appreciate!

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm trying to do the same thing for the x-axis. I tried similarly, but does work. Do you know how to do it? Thanks so much!

Comment: If I understand well this is what you want:

Comment: Plot[{5 x, 10 x, 20 x, , x (20 - x)}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 150},
 Ticks -> {{{3, Style[Overscript["ω", _], 16]}},
   {{100, Style[Overscript["ω", _], 16]}}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["g", 16], Style["ω", 16]}
 ]

Comment: wonderful! Many thanks!

Comment: should this work for `DiscretePlot` as well? I tried but it doesn't work.